# MF Sidemenu problems using dynamic data

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I have a problem because I want to put dynamic data in my sidemenuץ

I am using [MFSideMenu][1] with Xcode 5 for ios 7.0 and I have created a `SideMenuViewController` : `UITableViewController` where I design and populate data in my sidemenu.

When I start the app it shows all the data correctly, which I am getting from an API and storing in a mutable array.And also from a local database in the app.

When I log in with another user, without closing the app. I receive the correct Data from the API, and the `numberOfRowsInSection` shows the correct amount.

But when the app comes to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it acts upon the old data that populated the mutable array before, and not the new data. Somehow it is saved, even though I empty the mutable array, and now the SIDEMENU still shows the old data.

I have trying reloading the `tableview`, but that doesn´t work. It reloads the tableview but acts upon the old data. I made it call the `viewdidload` again, but that doesnt change anything. The only thing that makes the app show the correct data, is if I restart the app.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.callToServerEngine = [CallToServerEngine new];
        [self getMyData];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.callToServerEngine = [CallToServerEngine new];
    [DataBaseEngine new];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.allMyData = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self.allMyData removeAllObjects];
}
```

So my question what can be wrong, is it possible to use dynamic data in the sidemenu, and if so what is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT TO GET DATA

```
-(void)getMyData{

      [self.callToServerEngine getAllMyData postNotificationName:GetAllMyDataForSideMenuVC];

        SideMenuViewController *weakself = self;
        __block id refreshSuccess;
        refreshSuccess = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]    addObserverForName:GetAllMyDataForSideMenuVC

                                                                           object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                                                weakself.allMyData = [NSMutableArray new];
                                                                               [weakself.allData removeAllObjects];

                                                                               weakself.allMyData = [note.userInfo objectForKey:@"data"];

                                                                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                               NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
                                                                               [self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                                                           });
                                                                               [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:refreshSuccess];
                                                                                       refreshSuccess = nil;

    }];
```

APPDELEGATE

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
//container.menuContainerView.translates

UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];


UITableViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuVC"];

[container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
[container setCenterViewController:navigationController];


container.panMode= MFSideMenuPanModeCenterViewController | MFSideMenuPanModeSideMenu;

//container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeCenterViewController;
self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a possible solution with my comments to the question. Try reloading your UITableView on the main thread. UI updates should ALWAYS be done on the main thread, else it leads to a host of explicable problems.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [tableview reloadData];
        });
```

or you could also reload the UITableView section that displays the data like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    });
```

Comment: Sry for being a noob, what do you mean by the main thread, like should I call this method in viewDidLoad, or after I get my data?

Comment: No worries, you should call this after you get your data. Try replacing [weakself.tableView reloadData]; code with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [weakself.tableView reloadData];
        });

Comment: The first one does not seem to do it, and for the second one, I have in total 4 sections. Should I just loop through them all and call the self.tableView reloadSections four times?

Comment: Strange. I thought that would work. For the second part, you do not need to loop through the sections four times. Just create an indexset like so with your section indexes NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]; pass this to reloadSections:

Comment: The problems is still there, 

It comes back to the getData function and the reloadTableview you posted. It gets to the numberofRows with the right amount, but then when coming to the cell it talks to the old data on the same array. 

I have another data in the sidemenu which is from my local database. When these values changes it just doesnt show anything compared to the one from the the values from the api. It is like it cant relate to that old data.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic values only updated when I restarted the app, which meant when the class was first initialized it worked. So thats why I tried to call the same class again whenever I press the sidemenu to slide the menu.

UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.menuContainerViewController.leftMenuViewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuVC"];

This worked for me, maybe not the nicest solution but it fixed my problems.